# Can I call an exported default function inside the same file?

Tags: javascript

I have this structure in my code:

```
export default async function () {
    someCode();
}

export async function someOtherFunction() {
    tryingToCallTheDefaultFunction();
}
```

How can I call the default function in the same file as default function?
I know that it is possible when using named default exports. Is there another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure this is entirely possible. You can call the default function within the same file. You can achieve this by assigning the default export to a variable and then calling that variable as a function. Here's an example based on your code:

```
const defaultFunction = async function () {
    // some code
    await someCode();
}

export default defaultFunction;

export async function someOtherFunction() {
    // Calling the default function
    await defaultFunction();
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, thanks @Bishal Khatri! But my goal was not to name the default function. This is not directly "naming" the default function but my goal was to have no names like using `this` or something similar.

Comment: You can do this like this

```
export default async function () {
    console.log("Default function called");
}

export async function someOtherFunction() {
    // Call the default function directly
    await default(); 
}

// You can call the default function directly in the same module
default(); 

```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. I just tested it. If it works on your site, please send me a JSBin or something to test it. Thank you very much :)